# How to use preventDefault on dynamic elements?

Tags: jquery, forms, dynamic, preventdefault

I have a bunch of forms that get dynamically created and added to a div. The id of each form is also dynamically created - the ids are always different, but they all start with...

```
updateFRM_
```

I can't get preventDefault() to work - I'm not sure if that's the problem, or if the syntax is so incorrect that the js is failing and reloading.

What's the correct syntax for setting up listeners for forms that are both dynamically generated and dynamcially named?

```
$( "#updater" ).on( "submit", "form[id^='updateFRM_']", function(e)
{ 
    e.preventDefault();
```

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: How can your form have multiple ids? It has `#updater` and `#updateFRM_`

Comment: Is #updater dynamically created also?? .. try $('body')  instead of $( "#updater" )

Comment: I think your code should work, provided that `#updater` is a static element. Ie. was present when the dom was loaded, is it?

Comment: Thanks guys. The dynamic ids are added via mustache, so, eg id="updateFRM_432". #updater is static - part of the html page from the start.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the `$(document)` selector, you can target elements that are dynamically generated. This is because the document covers the dom and not just the html that is loaded initially. Below are two examples on what you can do. It depends entirely on your code and the way you are going to use this which of the two you pick.

#### ID based

```
var formid = 'someformid';
$(document).on('submit', '#' + formid, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do your form stuff
    return false;
});
```

#### Class based

```
$(document).on('submit', '.my-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formid = $(this).attr('id');
    // Do stuff with the formid 
    return false;
});
```

#### Update

The `return false;` is not required. I added it in case `e.preventDefault()` fails. Some jQuery versions have different ways of preventing the default action. Using a `return false;` does the same thing. It executes the code above and then, instead of doing the default action returns `false`.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think your class idea is the best way for me to go, but It's still auto-submitting. The class I'm using is responsiveFormPadded updateAdForm, so my listener looks like $( "#updater" ).on('submit', '.responsiveFormPadded updaterForm', function(e) {... <<is that correct?

Comment: I also tried $(document).on('submit', '.responsiveFormPadded updaterForm', function(e) {...

Comment: Never mind!!! Found my mistake - the class part should be '.responsiveFormPadded.updaterForm' - THANK YOU!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 $(function(){
    $("form[id^='updateFRM_']").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the forms a class, like `.prevent-default` and manipulate them that way.  Dealing with dynamically generated IDs is a huge hassle, especially with CSS selectors.